# Powerbi exportTo api bookmark state error

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have generated power-bi report into react App using service principle and I'm using exportTo post api to get report in ppt/pdf format

```
let result = await fetch(
      `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${data.workSpaceId}/reports/${data.reportId.id}/ExportTo`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      }
    );
 
formData = {
      format: "PPTX",
      powerBIReportConfiguration: {},
    };
    formData.powerBIReportConfiguration["identities"] = [
      {
        username: data.user.email,
        roles: ["RLS"],
        datasets: ["xyz"],
      },
    ];
    formData.powerBIReportConfiguration["pages"] = [{ pageName: data.page }],
    formData.powerBIReportConfiguration["defaultBookmark"] =
      data.bookMark.body.state;
}
```

I have used report.bookmark.Capture() and report.bookmarksManager.applyState() to apply and get bookmark state of app based on user interaction.But as I add bookmark state property in FormData I get

"**Error converting value** Error converting value "H4sIAAAAAAAAA+VZbW/bNhD+K4G+dAOcgqJtvfRbXlqsWLoGcZFhGIKBIs82W1nUKCqJF/i/70hKcfySxk7aJfWCILHIu+PdPXfH8+kmELIqczb9jU0geBMcKvVlwvSXvTDoBMXimkh6UchoN+YJBxqydBhRpFKlkaqogjc3gWF6BOZcVjXLrUBc/POiE7A8P2Uj+2R0DZ2gBF2pguXyH/C0uDPEvzDrBHBd5kozK3JgmAEr9hLp8RlVCV938UTGjbyEAXDjV8+gVNq0z51gKHODLJY1m769LjWqcdNa885tCg5dkvZImIQRzwjtQo8gp5mWluYIDx4pLTnLb8VZaeetIrQTvNNq4uQ2nrOUbwsjzRQfThSyHqOUTyzL4S8WQxhRHu5nrE/20Yt8P4ko3U+BZP0+gRB/kf2TO53M0GW/j0GDE3+kCiG9oXiWMvaftQmqqll8XyyuVQ1fXk+KVeqBqjWHMxjOH5z2M3T+qVaIjbPgD2Aa11CVc5bXDkkUeiLRE+gU6wu7jIRFnVvmi4uZ/bnwEN457xeJHJqPpydwCfmqPrf7q1utOudMSx8RjbpftekWBOt/Z1aD0K2YYMHSD6owY0d3RxXHvDdfsNuNAa1rOsFYXR1pQEIRvAk7AWd8DOJ4nk8eCCmsVhXHA9+7j0dqUqIqldd9/vSrLHCf2IOGxm9tAOGTYm496J3gTI7GToX7AZ9ZusXi8dNhzoovPwcYBTYOKp+QLg8XU9TmtEt8DG7DZNEkK4mo6JPekERhnyd9QggQu74+n5tcPRCXrOAIwXLgHYxGGkasPXDRhdu5dsByBHPJWW5x72Ci6sK4vXd10ZhHlqODzDo364sLPFWtT6C1NEpPl/U7g5Hl/g9V+agF6GU1jsasKCBfo4eLEVmM8uYWmIeFL4TBhJX2fsk+Y9hY9Gdt6Ufxn+8EV2PGdPO6t60LL1y0D2MQ0E8JZ4ywkPBuwuIH4/NrPt692jhnuC/m/u/5+q2ThCEtsmuzfarsbvj5fI2jbMgT1gdOe1TwKAQSPv4++QCsqvXGJrbkS0jXFWjXiT4Cas60WETZCgnDnohFL6UsAp4lPIn6ya7cmo9wCT7YDDv0IX4sddtzYM/+9gWZamMUwUu6kGZpSkIh+hmlEVD6IsBDO0TNzUqhauvHoj30x4Vua0M9cHGvB8Mo4zzkMWGUJiyFlwzc3eVdxu1eO5t8i0k3gShK0qgbQULitOe/nn3NYgPXJlPXq6U3EUnCoU85JbxP0yiK04dL7/P2Ez9cI/ZgPJYS1vY/P8o18J2+1DwQF75DSskwZWmGWYEXUBKFnMZP6JB2r59cO+rZICarXHL0/t2IDCagR86gERR+poIuLb1yEqq52xc/PfvM8XnHi5SEyUk7X3QzRuQRzLA17pso4RwMLmDXint1jBxCXRWv/Ajrwo6p8rY2rEisDNZpM3BQDxzdA/LdGLsRPbu/CIXLRWhnU+fe+naL+w4bb+uEnwr7tw7NbPi9gcluzobbbF0zHLZbgU8K0eMU+64sITROCelxEmUvonfeobnR99Bjk69Kz6bFoM74/Yps0EVeKuOyY6M52pm62uIe3MaD38UdWIS91McovVk76UBlhRXlXtz6k7TK3SfvMFQjtxXS7/1dg57iYW6/MeP1rSuQVlanEuUL/97YumYty11THReal7OyahlXBCGRVv5NqhTgzGxvI/tyq7m6M5EBpMMwTrrdvkiyLs2eUKW+zfTwyBYhjc3J3v7euYQrPOgbzRFdxV7XraraVCXjcMoKWNMhOdAFiK36otnsXwx1o/Z4IAAA" to type 'Microsoft.PowerBI.ServiceContracts.Api.V1.PageBookmark **to type 'Microsoft.PowerBI.ServiceContracts.Api.V1.PageBookmark**

My power-bi-client version : ^2.22.0

I have used Express and Node.js for backend server. Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

The ExportTo API doesn't interact with your client-side javascript application.  The bookmark you set in powerBIReportConfiguration has to be a bookmark saved in the service.

Comment: yes @David. I have saved bookmark in service only by sending it from client to service via custom API call . I have edited correct error I get  in ques. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

My payload format was wrong. defaultBookmark value should be object

formData.powerBIReportConfiguration["defaultBookmark"] = {state:data.bookMark.body.state};